# comparision of the Bruhat-tits tree with lattices in $\mathbb{R}^2$ || request for resources

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, projective-space, bruhat-tits-theory

I am writing an expository paper on the comparision of the bruhat-tits tree with lattices in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are in bijection with the upper half-plane modulo the group $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. But so far I haven't been able to find any resources for the same, especially on "lattices in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are in bijection with the upper half-plane modulo the group $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$". Would anyone happen to know any good papers / notes on the same?

Comment: How did you pick this topic without knowing any references for it?

Comment: @KCd it is part of assigned coursework. i didn't really have much choice! also i found this paper (https://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/667.2010/Atefeh.pdf) but it doesn't help much with the comparison.

Comment: You were told to write on a topic and given zero references? Well, see the first chapter of Silverman’s Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves for a description of lattices in $\mathbf C$ and the upper half-plane. Books on trees (e.g., by Serre) will describe lattices in $\mathbf Q_p^2$ up to equivalence.

Comment: okay, i'll go through them! thanks so much

Comment: In $\mathbf R^2$, a lattice is a subgroup $L$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z^2$ and is "spread out everywhere" (not a copy of $\mathbf Z^2$ in the real line like $\mathbf Z + \mathbf Z\sqrt{2}$, for instance).  Topologically, this says $L$ is both *discrete* and *cocompact* (the quotient group $\mathbf R^2/L$ is compact). In $\mathbf Q_p^2$, a lattice is a subgroup $L$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z_p^2$, which can be described as being *compact* and *open* in $\mathbf Q_p^2$, and the openness makes the quotient group $\mathbf Q_p^2/L$ discrete, so $L$ is *compact* and *co-discrete*.